# Accessing 6th generation iPod nano on linux

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

I've been trying to access a 6th generation iPod nano on linux. I tried the gtkpod that comes with Debian Squeeze and it seems it doesn't support the 6th generation nano. So I tried iTunes under wine and it barely installed and wasn't very functional. Then I tried foobar2000 under wine, which did install but didn't seem to detect my ipod.

I've now tried to compile gtkpod 2.0.2, but I'm getting issues with libtool trying to compile libgpod, and I don't even know if gtkpod 2.0.2 supports the 6th generation nano, although I did see a few references to the 6th generation nano in gtkpod's changelog.

Anyone know the best approach here?

Answer (score 2):

#### Warning: the following solution should ONLY be used for iPod nano 6th gen.

The following is said on the [gtkpod homepage](http://www.gtkpod.org/index.php?title=Home):

> The ipod nano 6th generation CANNOT be written to unless a binary-only blob is used

The binary (originally written for Ubuntu 12.04) can be downloaded and extracted from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1611473&page=4&p=12606043#post12606043) or [here](https://github.com/denydias/libhashab) and should work on Ubuntu (I tested it on Ubuntu 18.04) and Slackware.

You can find out if your system is 64-bit or 32-bit with the command `uname -i`. It will return `i386` for 32-bit and `x86_64` for 64-bit.

- Extract the archive file.
- Read the readme.md.

For 64-bit Ubuntu run:

```
sudo ./install_64bit.sh
```

For 32-bit Ubuntu run:

```
sudo ./install_32bit.sh
```

After that libgpod-based software like gtkpod, Banshee, Rhythmbox, Amarok, Clementine (and its new fork Strawberry), gPodder and a few others should work with iPod nano 6th gen.

Comment: this lib now lives here for [ubuntu](https://github.com/Amoystyle/libhashab) (and here for [slackware](https://github.com/neheb/libhashab)), then simply running the script immediately made my nano 6th gen work perfectly on Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

Well...  I just compiled gtkpod 2.0.2 and libgpod 0.8.2 and didn't get it to work.  ALTHOUGH in the readme it seems to indicate that you COULD get it to work if you got a file that was already on that and did some reverse hackery to get the hash72.  Sounds like a bit of work and I haven't done that yet.  I'll be trying, but need to load some music on it first.

What's odd is that gtkpod did copy files over, just not seen on the nano.  I'm sure I need to get the hash correct then I'll be ok.

Comment: Did you every try this again? I'm trying it out now.

Comment: I believe I did, I don't recall the result though.  I do have music on there so I don't remember if I got it through that or some other open  source application.  Did you try with the latest gtkpod and libgpod?